# multiple graphs in one view controller

Tags: ios, core-plot

currently in my little club app i'm writing i have a one graph in my hostingView.
is it possible to have a couple of scatter graphs in one view controller with core plus? 
my current code for setting up the space is below:

```
self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 355)];
[self.view addSubview:self.hostView];
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
[graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];
self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
```

how would i go about creating a second scatter graph below my first.
current page for app looks like this:

[image]

Comment: if you are using storyboard you can go for container view and add another graph below the first one in that view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second hosting view to the view controller and use it to host a second graph.

Comment: The first parameter is the plot that is requesting data. Use that to decide what value to return. The datasource doesn't need to know or care about the plot space. The data is the data. The plot space defines a mapping between data coordinates and the drawing coordinates in the plot area layer.